# requestFullscreen works no more in message event handler

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, postmessage, html5-fullscreen

User clicks a button and in `click` event handler we `postMessage` to iframe. Iframe handles it in `message` event handler and calls `element.requestFullscreen()`. In older browsers it worked (eg. in Chrome 65) but in current (72) it errors with `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`.

Is there a way to transfer "gesture initiated" flag in `postMessage` call?

Note that iframe has `allow="fullscreen"` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always with iframes, it depends on here it is hosted relative to the parent document.

If you are running a **same-origin** document in that frame, then you can simply call `requestFullScreen` directly on the element you wish form the main doc:

```
const frameDoc = frame.contentDocument;
frameDoc.getElementById('el-to-fs').requestFullscreen(); // assuming polyfill
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdpe8nkq/) <sub>Since StackSnippets® overly protected iframes won't allow access nor fullscreen.</sub>

---

But if you were, you wouldn't have had this issue in Chrome (you'd still have had in FF).

Because even though it is true that this method [requires an user-gesture](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation), `postMessage` being fast enough, you are [able to use it with a same-origin frame](https://jsfiddle.net/k3srz8n6/) in Chrome.

What happens in this browser is that a *cross-origin* document must have received an user-gesture before being able to call `requestFullscreen`.
Once the cross-origin frame has been marked as interacted-by-the-user, then you'll be able to call `requestFullscreen` even from main-doc's events: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3srz8n6/1/) (still, only in Chrome).

But, for a cross-browser solution, you'd have to

- load this content as same-origin (e.g using a proxy)
- or to use a small hack where you set the `<iframe>` in fullscreen mode and let the inner document know you did so, so it can style its document accordingly: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3srz8n6/2/)
  **main.js**

  ```
  onclick = e => {
    frame.contentWindow.postMessage("you're going fullscreen", '*');
    frame.requestFullscreen();
  };
  ```

  **frame.js**

  ```
  onmessage = e => {
    if(message.data === "you're going fullscreen") {
      // trigger our special fullscreen CSS
      document.documentElement.classList.add('fullscreen');
      // do some DOM cleaning if needed
    }
    else if(message.data === "you're exiting fullscreen") {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('fullscreen');
    }
  };
  ```

Comment: In our case is cross-origin. Thanks for the "small hack", that could help us.